# MySQL event scheduler in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, configuration, xampp

According to the MySQL documentation, to enable the event scheduler permanently I have to insert the following line in the my.ini (there is no my.cnf file in the mysql folder in **XAMPP**) somewhere in the [mysqld] section:

```
event_scheduler=ON
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Every time I restart the computer, the event scheduler is set to OFF, and I have to set it to ON manually (using the `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` command).

Does anybody know a solution for this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Is your 'event scheduler' working now?  We would like to confirm you have been successful.

Answer (score 5):

Here the path for my.ini on XAMPP

xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

Open my.ini  and add the following

 
`[mysqld]`

`event_scheduler=ON`

then restart mySql service.

To check the status use the below mySql query

SELECT @@event_scheduler

Comment: That's the answer! Simple and effective.

Answer (score 4):

The "event_scheduler" with the underscore is the variable name of this option, to turn on the event scheduler in the config file you have to use the correct format with a dash:

```
event-scheduler=ON
```

This is a bit confusing as both dash and underscore are used in options in the config file. You should use the server system variables reference when you want to figure out the proper syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler

Also, make sure that the option in the configuration file is defined under the [mysqld] header, and not under [client] or [mysqld_safe], because it's not picked up from those places.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP (xampp-osx-7.2.30-0-installer.dmg) for MAC OS(catalina)

Go to Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf and add

`event_scheduler=ON`

on line 39 for instance

The **my.cnf** files will looks like:

```
...
    # The MySQL server
    default-character-set=utf8mb4
    [mysqld]
    user=mysql
    port=3306
    socket      =/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
    key_buffer=16M
    max_allowed_packet=1M
    table_open_cache=64
    sort_buffer_size=512K
    net_buffer_length=8K
    read_buffer_size=256K
    read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
    myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
    event_scheduler=ON # ADD THIS LINE
...
```

> **Restart the server (MySQl Database from XAMPP console) afterwards !**